# Verificar tema de texto php

Tags: php

Tenho um mini reconhecedor de texto onde ele deve comparar se as palavras do texto principal, existem em um texto de palavras chaves:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Pesquisa</title>
</head>
<?PHP
$texto1 = file_get_contents('teste.txt');
//adiciona o texto em posições do array
preg_match_all('|texto\d+(.+?)<\/body>|is', $texto1, $resultado);
$textos = $resultado[1];
//textos[0] ...

$arrayCot = explode(" ", file_get_contents('PalavrasCot.txt')); // arquivo com as palavras a serem guardadas
$arrayEmp = explode(" ", file_get_contents('PalavrasEmp.txt')); // arquivo com as palavras a serem guardadas
$arrayDir = explode(" ", file_get_contents('PalavrasDir.txt')); // arquivo com as palavras a serem guardadas
$arrayEsp = explode(" ", file_get_contents('PalavrasEsp.txt')); // arquivo com as palavras a serem guardadas
$arrayPol = explode(" ", file_get_contents('PalavrasPol.txt')); // arquivo com as palavras a serem guardadas
$arrayVp = explode(" ", file_get_contents('PalavrasVp.txt')); // arquivo com as palavras a serem guardadas
$contCot = 0;
$contEmp = 0;
$contDir = 0;
$contEsp = 0;
$contPol = 0;
$contVp = 0;
$qtd = sizeof($textos);

//echo $qtd;

$tema == "Cotidiano";
for($n = 0; $n < $qtd; $n++){
    $arra = array($textos[$n]);
    if($tema == "Cotidiano"){
        foreach($arrayCot as $valor){
            if(in_array($valor, $arra)){
                echo $valor."\n";
                echo $contCot++;
            }
        }
    }
    $tema = "Emprego";
    if($tema == "Emprego"){
        foreach($arrayEmp as $valor){
            if(in_array($valor, $arra)){
                echo $valor."\n";
                $contEmp++;
            }
        }
    }
    $tema = "Direitos";
    if($tema == "Direitos"){
        foreach($arrayDir as $valor){
            if(in_array($valor, $arra)){
                echo $valor."\n";
                $contDir++;
            }
        }
    }
    $tema = "Esportes";
    if($tema == "Esportes"){
        foreach($arrayEsp as $valor){
            if(in_array($valor, $arra)){
                echo $valor."\n";
                $contEsp++;
            }
        }
    }
    $tema = "Policial";
    if($tema == "Policial"){
        foreach($arrayPol as $valor){
            if(in_array($valor, $arra)){
                echo $valor."\n";
                $contPol++;
            }
        }
    }
    $tema = "VidaPublica";
    if($tema == "VidaPublica"){
        foreach($arrayVp as $valor){
            if(in_array($valor, $arra)){
                echo $valor."\n";
                $contVp++;
            }
        }
    }
    $tema = "Cotidiano";                    
}
?>
</html>
```

Como está o texto em teste.txt:

```
TEXTO1
<head> <edic><Diário Gaúcho 12/05/2013</edic>
<autor>Denise Waskow, denise.waskow@diariogaucho.com.br</autor>
</head>
<body>
<subtítulo>Para celebrar</subtítulo>
<título>Mães e filhos se divertem em atividades culturais no Parque da Redenção</título>
Jogos de mesa, futebol, brinquedos infláveis, teatro, dança e uma série de outras brincadeiras movimentaram o domingo no parque
Criançada aproveitou o domingo nos brinquedos
Denise Waskow
denise.waskow@diariogaucho.com.br
Se existe algo que deixa toda mãe realizada é ver que o filho está feliz. E quem levou a prole neste domingo à Redenção ganhou esse presente para celebrar o Dia das Mães. 
Jogos de mesa, futebol, brinquedos infláveis, teatro, dança e uma série de outras brincadeiras movimentaram o domingo, em uma ação promovida pela Secretaria Municipal de Esporte, Recreação e Lazer da Capital. A gurizada aproveitou muito, e as mamães se emocionaram com a alegria deles.
<subtítulo>Diversão nos brinquedos</subtítulo>
Enquanto a pequena Amanda, três anos, criava coragem para descer no tobogã inflável, a mãe, a babá Roselaine Pereira, 30 anos, ficava na parte de baixo do brinquedo, incentivando a menina a descer, fotografando e se divertindo junto.  
- É maravilhoso, é ótimo. O melhor presente é isso, a felicidade deles - derrete-se.
O filho mais velho, Jhonattan, 13 anos, já não está mais na fase de brincar, mas nem por isso deixou de acompanhar a mãe. Enquanto a irmã caçula passava de um brinquedo para o outro, ele contou como homenageou Roselaine no início do domingo: 
- Eu disse que eu amo ela.
<subtítulo>Uma torcida especial</subtítulo>
"Vai Joana, vai Joana!". Ao lado do espaço demarcado para o futebol, a massoterapeuta Tânia Regina Horta, 46 anos, incentivava a filha caçula, de seis anos, no esporte. E apesar de a mãe ser gremista e a filha colorada, não existe rivalidade. O que conta nessa relação, claro, é o amor. 
- A mãe que está sendo homenageada e são os filhos que se divertem. Está ótimo, o melhor é curtir a companhia deles - elogia. 
Depois de uma manhã inteira de brincadeiras, o planejamento de Tânia era encontrar os dois filhos mais velhos, além dos dois enteados, para o tradicional almoço de Dia das Mães.
</body>


TEXTO2
<head> <edic><Diário Gaúcho 14/05/2013</edic>
<autor></autor>
</head>
<body>
<subtítulo>Colisão</subtítulo>
<título>Sargento dos Bombeiros morre em acidente na zona sul da Capital</título>
Itiberê Poty de Abreu perdeu o controle da moto após colidir com um carro
Trânsito ficou em meia pista na Avenida Wenceslau Escobar
Um motociclista morreu após colidir hoje com um carro na Avenida Wenceslau Escobar, na zona sul de Porto Alegre. Itiberê Poty de Abreu, 49 anos, era sargento do Corpo de Bombeiros.
A vítima subia a avenida quando colidiu com o carro da frente e perdeu o controle da moto. Um outro veículo que trafegava no sentido contrário não conseguiu desviar e também se envolveu no acidente. O motociclista morreu no local.
O trânsito ficou em meia pista na Avenida Wenceslau Escobar e seria liberado após a remoção da vítima.
</body>
```

E em PalavrasCot.txt:

```
parque. parque, parque brincadeiras. brincadeiras, brincadeiras mães mães, mães. filho, filho. filho acidente. acidente, acidente venda venda, venda. família família natureza, natureza. natureza carro. carro, carro crianças, crianças. crianças escola, escola. escola
```

Problema: Não estou conseguindo ver onde está o erro, pois ele acaba não achando nenhuma palavra que se encontra no arquivo de pesquisa.

Comment: vc ta dando um explode no espaço nos txt que devem ser varridos usa preg_match com uma expressão regular

Comment: @JasarOrion Realizei a seguinte alteração:
`$arrayCot = file_get_contents('palavras.txt');` 
`$lines = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', trim($arrayCot));`
Mas acabou não funcionando com a expressão regular e nem com o trim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem pequenos erros no código.

```
$tema == "Cotidiano";
```

O operador [`==`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.comparison.php) é usado para comparação, use `=` para atribuição de valor.

```
for($n = 0; $n < $qtd; $n++){
    $arra = array($textos[$n]);

    if($tema == "Cotidiano"){
        foreach($arrayCot as $valor){
            if(in_array($valor, $arra)){
```

A variável `$textos[$n]` é uma *string*, `$arra` é um `array` com um item somente, um texto com muitas palavras. Use o [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php) para separar as linhas por quebra de linha:

```
for($n = 0; $n < $qtd; $n++) {
    $arra = explode("\n", $textos[$n]);

    // ...
```

Feito essas alterações, o código talvez funcione do modo esperado, porém veja o seguinte:

```
for($n = 0; $n < $qtd; $n++){
    $arra = explode("\n", $textos[$n]);
    // ...   

        foreach($arrayCot as $valor){
            if(in_array($valor, $arra)){
               // ...
            }
        }
 // ...
}
```

As palavras do arquivo `PalavrasCot.txt` (armazenadas em `$arrayCot`) serão comparadas com as **linhas inteiras** dos textos. Por exemplo, só vai achar a palavra *brincadeiras*, se ela ocupar uma linha inteira, caso contrário não encontrará a palavra.

Se você quiser verificar se a palavra está presente na linha, use o [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strpos.php) (ou [`stripos`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.stripos.php) para não diferenciar maiúsculas e minúsculas).

```
for($n = 0; $n < $qtd; $n++) {
    $arra = $textos[$n]; // Não é um array, somente uma string

    if($tema == "Cotidiano"){
        foreach($arrayCot as $valor){
            if (strpos($arra, $valor) !== false) {
                echo $valor . "\n";
                echo $contCot++ . "\n";
            }
        }
    }

    // ... Siga o mesmo raciocínio nos códigos que seguem.
}
```

<kbd>[Ver **DEMO**](http://ideone.com/Sf0KFY)</kbd>

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Fiz as alterações para o que eu necessitava !!